# Azure blob storage 12.5.0 dependency removed from maven central repo

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management, azure-blob-storage, maven-central

I Have been using [Azure blob storage 12.5.0](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/azure/azure-storage-blob/12.5.0/) to develop a java application for talking to blob storage. Everything was working fine but suddenly now when i compile my maven project it says dependency not found. Going through this [link for 12.5.0](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/azure/azure-storage-blob/12.5.0/), I now get a page not found error. I am struggling to understand why this dependency was suddenly removed or is this some backend issue? Apparently all dependencies below 12.6.0 now give me not found error.

I cannot use 12.7.0 and beyond because that has an internal dependency on reactor core version >=3.3.5 and my project is running on reactor core 3.3.2 and upgrading it is not an option right now.

This is how I am using this dependency in my project. Nothing fancy here though. Would be great if someone can fill me in on what's going on here.

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
    <version>12.5.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Don't you have a copy of the 12.5.0 in your local repository or your Nexus/Artifactory?

Comment: No. I was running it in local so far so it was just in my local cache and was never pushed to nexus. Unfortunately I had to  reinstall my Os yesterday because of some other issue and even that local cache is gone now.

Comment: Interesting, as far as I'm aware Sonatype (who own/manage Maven Central) doesn't normally remove things from Maven Central. The fact the directory is listed in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/azure/azure-storage-blob/ would seem to indicate it is somehow blocked. You may want to consider contacting Sonatype to ask about this.

Comment: Have raised a ticket with them. Hopeful to get some response soon - https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-6914

Comment: @Kunalgupta Good to hear. I also [pinged them on Twitter](https://twitter.com/Avalanche1979/status/1428647570088284160). Unfortunately, I can't open that ticket (I can see other tickets in MVNCENTRAL, so maybe it was moved?).

Comment: I can still access it. Microsoft got them removed due to some data corruption issues apparently but very odd that those were removed just like that.https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-72181

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is related to this https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-72181 It was an exceptional case due to the complexity of the data loss.

Comment: I was about to paste ithis ticket here. Just saw your answer. Guess I will have to work with 12.7.0.